# What was the first ever continuity error in Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who, continuity

I was reading Paul Cornell's blog post on [Canonicity in Doctor Who](https://www.paulcornell.com/2007/02/canonicity-in-doctor-who/)

And thought this challenge would make for a fun question (emphasis mine):

> Not giving a toss about how it all fits together is one of Doctor Who’s oldest, proudest traditions, a strength of the series. **(And a No Prize to the person who points out the first ever continuity error in the original series.)**

So, have at it. What's the earliest continuity error you can find?

Comment: *"When Ian and Barbara enter the TARDIS for the first time, Susan operates the door switch. Later on, when the Doctor electrocutes Ian, he uses the exact same switch"* - Season 1, episode 1 https://www.moviemistakes.com/tv3572

Comment: @Valorum Being the TARDIS, it doesn't seem that unlikely that the same switch can do two different things.

Comment: Perhaps it might be better to look for the first major issue that required a retcon, rather than a disappearing prop or other minor error. In that case, the origin of the Cybermen would be a candidate.

Comment: I am guessing *time travel*?